# FOR executado de forma assícrona

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Existe alguma forma de executar um **FOR** de maneira assíncrona?

O que acontece é o seguinte, meu programa recupera um numero grande de dados do banco, processa eles e devolve o resultado ao usuário. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
queryset = Model.objects.raw(seleciono os dados que quero do banco)

for res in queryset:
    processamento_dos_dados

return resultado_do_processamento
```

O problema é que muitas vezes é recuperado um volume grande de dados, fazendo com que leve um certo tempo até que seja dado um retorno para o usuário. Eu não tenho como modificar o processamento dos dados, por isso surgiu a dúvida se é possível executar este FOR de maneira assíncrona.

Pesquisando a respeito, encontrei sobre a **Celery** e **AsynciO**, porém, todos os exemplos são com a utilização de funções, e não com laços de repetição.

Comment: Willian, o assunto é um pouco complexo mas para que você consiga resolver seu problema é necessário entender que o módulo `asyncio` não paraleliza seu código diretamente nas suas CPUs, o que ele faz é um "revezamento" para executar algo enquanto aguarda a resposta de uma operação de IO - Input/Output(como escrita ao HD, resposta da placa de rede, etc...). Menciono isso pois se `processamento_dos_dados` for algo que será processado na CPU você não tirará proveito deste módulo.

Comment: O Celery pode ser uma boa opção pois você pode ter processos diferentes processando seus dados ou até computadores diferentes, porém você precisa avaliar se uma otimização no seu processamento de dados já não resolveria. Enfim, peço desculpas por não formular uma resposta real, mas apesar de conhecer o conceito ainda não implementei nada com Celery para poder exemplificar para você.

Comment: @fernandosavio Então cara, em relação ao processamento, o algotimo já foi feito pra ser da forma mais eficiente o possível. O grande problema é realmente a quantidade de dados que ele carrega, algumas vezes são poucas linhas, outras podem chegar a milhares. Ai, como tem que processar linha por linha, acaba demorando muito. Vou dar uma estudada melhor no Celery e ver se consigo usa-lo para resolver meu problema. Muito obrigado! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe uma forma de executar o `for` assíncrono ver esse [artigo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-for) da documentação oficial, porém não vai funcionar em uma `queryset` do Django por ser síncrono, aqui vai algumas sugestões para o seu problema

- Tente otimizar suas queries
- Refatorar seu algorítimo usando [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) pode melhorar em muito a performance
- Usar o Celery para orquestrar essas tarefas mais pesadas