# Trabalhar com querysets e Celery

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Seguindo o que havia perguntado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426469/for-executado-de-forma-ass%C3%ADcrona), sigo tentando executar meu código de maneira assíncrona. Estou tentando utilizar o Celery para executar esse procedimento, porém estou tendo alguns problemas.

Eu tinha o seguinte:

```
def get(self, request):

    queryset = Model.objects.raw() # Faço um MATCH com parametros digitados pelo usuario e valores do banco.

        for res in queryset:
            processamento_dos_dados

    return resultado_do_processamento
```

O que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

Com o Celery, no meu `tasks.py` coloquei minha função:

```
@shared_task
def teste(queryset, variavel1, lista1, variavel2, lista2):
    for res in queryset:
        processamento_de_dados # Aqui são alguns procedimentos de comparação necessarios para minha aplicação

    return lista2
```

Na minha `views.py`:

```
from .tasks import teste
class CLASSE(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        # Processamentos para gerar variavel1, lista1, variavel2
        queryset = Model.objects.raw() # Faço um MATCH com parametros digitados pelo usuario e valores do banco.

        lista2 = []
        lista2 = teste.delay(queryset, variavel1, lista1, variavel2, lista2)
```

Aqui é onde os problemas começam. Se eu tento passar da forma que está ali `teste.delay(variaveis)`, retorna um erro dizendo que ***o queryset não é um objeto JSON serializavel***. Se eu retiro o .delay, ele executa de maneira sincrona, como se não estivesse utilizando o Celery.

Pesquisando encontrei essa [possível solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable):

```
test = serializers.serializer('json', queryset)
lista2 = teste.delay(test, variavel1, lista1, variavel2, lista2)
```

Porém, o tempo de serialização para JSON é fora de cogitação (o código fica travado ali um tempão, não consegui em nenhum dos meus testes fazer ele passar da serialização).

Já tentei também trocar o .delay() por [.apply_async()](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.2.1/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=async#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async), porém não sei como fazer para passar todas as variáveis necessárias dentro do `args=`.

Outra solução que encontrei foi [esta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916413/celery-parallel-distributed-task-with-multiprocessing), porém mais uma vez, não sei como passar todos os parametros necessários para a execução da função.

Como indicado na minha primeira pergunta, tentei utilizar generators para otimizar meu código, porém, não senti diferença nenhuma na execução. Segui [isso aqui](https://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/), fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
queryset = Model.objects.raw() #MATCH de valores
for res in queryset.iterator():
```

Comment: Esse erro acontece só quando adicionas parametros? Recentemente, testei background worker e dava o mesmo erro ao utilizar para http requests. Vou partilhar a minha implementação com celery, utiliza parametros com o .delay().

Comment: Então, eu testei apenas com parametros, pois não consegui uma forma de utilizar minha função sem eles... Eu até consegui utilizar o .apply_async(), porém caio no mesmo erro do Queryset. Aparenemente não existe uma forma de passar o queryset como parametro para o Celery

Comment: Efetuas as consultas na task, isso é que deve ser na task, vai demorar tempo. Não passes o queryset.

Comment: Entretanto encontrei um post com a tua dificuldade, e com a minha sugestão e com outra, dá uma olhada. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765276/celery-raise-error-while-passing-my-queryset-obj-as-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você realmente não pode passar a queryset para o celery, precisa passar um objeto serializável, e provavelmente você está usando json como método de serialização, com isso, tem que passar algo que seja compatível com json.

No seu caso, se sua query não for muito cara, eu sugiro passar um lista de inteiros:

```
from .tasks import teste

class CLASSE(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Model.objects.raw()
        ids = list(queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
        teste.delay(queryset)
```

Note que o método delay não retorna nada que você possa usar, é assíncrono, então sua *lista2* não traria nada de útil.

Sua task seria mais ou menos assim:

```
@shared_task
def teste(ids, variavel1, lista1, variavel2, lista2):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
    for res in queryset:
        processamento_de_dados
```

Também não há sentido em retornar nada, pois é assíncrono. Suponha que seus workers estejam sobrecarregados e o celery demore 1 minuto para executar a task, qual seria o sentido em esperar 1 minuto para ver o resultado, vc está usando o celery justamente para evitar isso ;)

Se sua query for cara e você precisar torná-la também assíncrona, verifique como ela é composta.

Por exemplo, se sua query busca usuários que logaram em um número arbitrário de horas, definido no settings ou em alguma configuração dinâmica, para enviar uma newsletter, você poderia passar o valor da configuração e deixar para executar a query no celery, entende?

Comment: Olá @Michel Sabchuk, ok, eu to fazendo basicamente isso que tu explicou, mas, eu to tendo prolema justamente com o retorno. Como eu faço pra receber o retorno? no caso, minha lista2?

Comment: Não recebe, pelo menos não de forma síncrona. Lembre-se: o celery opera de forma assíncrona!

Vamos supor um exemplo prático: se sua tarefa é enviar uma newsletter para um conjunto de emails. Eu faria um modelo de dados para guardar as instâncias de envio, relacionaria os usuários desejados nesse modelo, faria a execução da task e, se eu precisasse ver o resultado, consultaria a instância que criei previamente, que poderia ser atualizada com um novo status ou novas informações quando a task tiver terminado.

Comment: Entao, acho que o Celery n vai resolver o meu problema então... O retorno do meu processamento de dados é um valor %, no caso, uma lista de valores, pq tipo, meu algoritmo calcula um valor para cada tupla retornada do banco de dados, e eu vou salvando esses valores em uma listal, ordeno ela e pego o primeiro valor (o menor resultado). Eu queria transformar isso de forma assincrona, pra tentar deixar ele mais rapido, mas to vendo que não to no caminho muito certo.

Comment: Provavelmente não. Se bem entendi, você tem uma view que processa os dados e os retorna na resposta. Isso é justamente síncrono ;)

O que pode estudar é fazer sua view engatilhar a tarefa e, ao mesmo tempo, marcar que a tarefa foi engatilhada. Na resposta, ao invés de mostrar o resultado, vc mostraria alguma informação avisando que está sendo processado.

Quando tiver terminado a tarefa, caso recarregasse a view, teria os dados atualizado e poderia rendenizar corretamente. No cliente, poderia recarregar periodicamente, ou carregar via ajax, ou ainda usar sockets...

Comment: É bem isso mesmo. Basicamente eu chamo uma view, essa view busca dados no banco, processa eles e retorna um resultado. Eu preciso agilizar esse processamento, por isso pensei em tentar paralelizar a execução do FOR (pq eu busco os dados no banco atraves de uma queryset e processo essa queryset dentro de um FOR, como ta ali na pergunta), para que ele executasse mais de um laço de cada vez. Mas pelo jeito não é possível. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Partilho o meu exemplo, com Celery e RabbitMQ, e parametros ao invocar tasks:

serializers.py

```
class SensorsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'raw_data': {'required': False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Custom create method to allow creating"""
        try:
            user = None
            request = self.context.get("request")
            if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
                user = request.user.id

            data = self.initial_data          
            save_sensors_rawdata.delay(data, user) # delay com parametros
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as error:
            Error.objects.create(user_id=user,raw_data_original=data, error_details="SensorsSerializer/create: "+str(error))
        finally:
            return Sensor(**validated_data)
```

tasks.py

```
@task
def save_sensors_rawdata(raw_data, user_id):
    """Save sensors Raw data"""
    try:
        Sensor.objects.create(user_id=user_id,
            raw_data=raw_data)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as error:
        Error.objects.create(user_id=user_id,raw_data_original=raw_data, 
            error_details="SensorsSerializer/Task/save_sensors_rawdata: "+str(error))
    finally:
        return raw_data
```

requirements.txt

```
celery==4.2.0
django-celery-beat==1.3.0
```

NOTA: Nesta abordagem m2m, tenho sensores que efetuam um POST com dados, crio uma task e respondo de imediato com Status 200 e o objeto recebido, uma vez que neste caso não efetuo alterações para a resposta. Neste projeto não tinha problema ser assim. Ou seja, após receber os dados, crio a task esta é enviada para RabbitMQ, logo que esteja um worker disponível, pega a task e então nesta cálculo várias métricas, faço update de algumas tabelas e insert noutras.
Compreendo que existem serviços em que esta abordagem não é possível ou não iria funcionar, mas neste caso funciona e muito bem.